# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException in Servlet.init()

Tags: spring, tomcat

I'm trying to build my first web app with Spring. I added an embedded Tomcat server in my main method but when I'm trying to run it I get the error below and I don't understand it. It's probably a problem of Spring configuration but I can't figure out what.

I pushed my project [here](https://github.com/gaetan-l/resume-builder-embedded-tomcat) so you can see it all.

Here is the error:

```
INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
sept. 29, 2023 11:46:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
sept. 29, 2023 11:46:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException-->com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.PersistenceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:501)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.wrapCachedClass(Enhancer.java:801)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.lambda$new$1(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.lambda$createEntry$1(LoadingCache.java:52)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:130)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:317)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:562)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:407)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4894)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485)
    at com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.Application.run(Application.java:91)
    at com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.Application.main(Application.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.PersistenceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2772)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:901)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:490)
    ... 52 more

sept. 29, 2023 11:46:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/resume-builder-1.0-SNAPSHOT] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.PersistenceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS([Lorg.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback;)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2772)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:901)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerFactoryData.<init>(Enhancer.java:490)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.wrapCachedClass(Enhancer.java:801)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.lambda$new$1(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.lambda$createEntry$1(LoadingCache.java:52)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:130)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:317)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:562)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:407)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4894)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485)
    at com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.Application.run(Application.java:91)
    at com.gaetanl.resumebuilder.Application.main(Application.java:32)
```

Comment: I don't know what the cause of this error is, but you can make this a lot easier by using Spring Boot. It takes care of Tomcat etc. for you, so that you don't need to configure and start it yourself.

Comment: It's complaining about what's presumably one of your own classes. Is it properly annotated, and public without a private constructor? Where is the class supposed to fit into your application?

Comment: @Jesper I know. I'm trying to get back to programming after a long hiatus and I feel like Boot is doing really too much thing under the hood that I don't understand. I will get to use it eventually, but for now I wanna learn how all of this works. But yeah, it's a hassle...

Comment: @nitind The PersistenceConfig class is where I define the PlatformTransactionManager and EntityManagerFactory manager beans, both in public methods. And the class is annotated with Configuration.